# SQLAlchemy - How to build a one-to-many relationship with an intermediary association table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, associations, one-to-many

I'm trying to describe a One-To-Many relationship using SQLAlchemy but I can't link two objects directly due to the database design itself.

```
 ____________       _______________________           _____________
|...parent...|     |....parent_children....| ------> |....child....|
|============|     |=======================|         |=============| 
|--int: id---|---> |----int: child_id------| ------> |---int: id---|
|------------|     |----int: parent_id-----|         |-------------|
|____________|     |_______________________| ------> |_____________|
```

- A **parent** can have **multiple children**
- A **child** can **only** have **one parent**

In pure SQL I'd have to do this:

```sql
-- Finding the parent of a child
SELECT p.* 
FROM child c
INNER JOIN parent_children pc ON pc.child_id = c.id
INNER JOIN parent p ON pc.parent_id = p.id
WHERE c.id = 2323 -- example

-- Finding parent childrens
SELECT c.* 
FROM parent p
INNER JOIN parent_children pc ON pc.parent_id = p.id
INNER JOIN child c ON pc.child_id = c.id
WHERE p.id = 32323 -- example****
```

Here's the minified model:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = # TODO: HOW TO populate the list of childrens here?

class ParentChild(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'parent_children'
   child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
   parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent = # TODO: How to populate the parent of this child here?
```

I've tried to follow [this documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-pattern) considering `ParentChild` as an Associate Table but it ends up adding `child_id` and `parent_id` whenever I use it to associate those two, as I'm not associating `Parent` to `Child` directly, but rather `Parent` to `ParentChild`

Comment: It sounds like you want to do the same thing as a many-to-many relationship with the addition of a unique constraint on `child_id` in the association table.

Comment: @GordThompson Indeed, you're right. After careful noob investigation of the real model, I've came up with a solution using what you've pointed.
I'll answer my own question with code though, just in case somebody faces this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class ParentChild(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'parent_children'
   child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True, unique=True)
   parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), index=True, nullable=False) 
  # ForeignKeyConstraint(['parent_id'], ['parent.id'],
  #                      use_alter=True, name='name_this_constraint_1')
  # UniqueConstraint('child_id', 'child.id', name='name_this_unique_constraint_2')
  # ForeignKeyConstraint(['child_id'], ['child.id'],
  #                      use_alter=True, name='name_this_constraint__3')
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)}

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship('Child',
                            secondary='parent_children',
                           )
```